# image grid keep proper resolution accross all devices and desktop without distortion

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid

i have created image grid using css but it look fine to desktop but when i go to moibile and tablet view the images distorts.is there a way so that it can be keep proper accross all devices.

Here is the fiddle for the example what i have done so far.

```
[Here is the fiddle][1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o6epbgoa/

Comment: Please put the relevant code in your post so that the question will still have meaning if the link were to disappear. Can you explain what the problem is and the result you are after?

Comment: Please look at the Fiddle in full screen views, the images are in the grid distrots on small devices like mobile and iPad. i wanted to auto adjust the image resolution across devices without distortion of images. Is there any way to do it.